# attaching a script dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem which have been troubling me for the last few days. I have to implement tracking to my website simply by adding a script tag as shown below.

```
<script src="domain">
```

However I need to attach the script tag once a javascript event is fired. I made some research and discovered this can be achieved using jQuery .getScript() function. Sample code shown below.

```
$('body').bind("success", function(e, data) {
    // Call for the tracking scipt here
    $.getScript("domain", function() {});
});
```

My problem is that the loaded script contains the below code:

```
document.write(<img src='domain'/>);
```

Unfortunately this code is not executed, (I am guessing since the DOM is already loaded at the time I am attaching the script, the document.write() function will not work.) I also tried using native javascript code as shown below to no avail.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];         
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "domain";
body.appendChild(script);
```

At the moment I have managed to achieve this by placing the scipt tag in a seperate page and then load the page in an invisible iFrame from the fired JS event. I don't really like this idea, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the `success` event? Is your `getScript` even running? You should use its callbacks to determine whether the request was successful or not. There is an example in their docs. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ `$.getScript("ajax/test.js")
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
  console.log( textStatus );
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
  alert( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});`

Comment: the success event is a custom event which I'm triggering from another script. I have tried $.getScript("ajax/text.js").done(function( script, textStatus) {}); the script gets loaded successfully but the document.write() function still didn't work out

Comment: What does `didn't work out` mean? It didn't fire? It did fire, but your js didn't execute? A failure fired instead? It is very unclear from your question where the failure is. Is your success event firing? Is the getScript code executing? Are you getting a callback?

Comment: problem is definitely the write which can't be done after page load... never tried this but perhaps you can parse the script somehow

Comment: What's the point of loading it via jQuery? Why not just add the line of script code as a regular line of HTML, e.g. `<script src="...`

Comment: @mrtsherman didn't work out means that the script was called and the response from $.getScript().done(function(script, textStatus){ console.log(textStatus) }); returns success however the content of the script is not executed.

Comment: @j08691 I can not add the script as a normal line of HTML as I need to execute the script only  once the event is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. But I doubt whether it will work on all browsers without quotes. So give

```
document.write("<img src='http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png'/>");
```

Or you can try jQuery

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", "http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png").appendTo("body");
```

I would suggest adding a `div` as the container of the image

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

and then in dynamic script use jQuery or palin javascript to add the image.

```
$("<img/>").attr("src", "http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png").appendTo("#container");
```

or

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
container.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: I do not have control on the script since the script is provided by a third party.

Comment: which is the browser in which you tested ? Chrome doesn't support `document.write` having parameter without quotes.

Comment: One more thing, is that the only line in the script file ?

Comment: Chrome, but the quotes are included i just forgot to include them in the post. Yes that is the only line returned by the script.